# Head.js screen size vs CSS3 @media query - why the former?

Tags: css, head.js

What is the advatange of using Head.js screen size detection over CSS3 media query?

**Head.js Screen size detection**

```
.lt-1024 #hero { background-image:(medium.jpg); }
```

**CSS3 @media query**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #hero { background-image:(medium.jpg); }
}
```

If it's just a matter of CSS vs JS choice, which one is more trustworthy for mobile design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS media queries are not supported by all mobile browsers (see [*Browser compatibility – viewports*](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/tableViewport.html#mediaqueries)). That’s why it could help to have another indicator.

But you can not only use this for mobile web sites but also for web site for desktop web browsers.

Comment: I see. Media queries are still more "elegant" but compatibility can be a priority. Thanks!